# PubSub testing in NodeJS testing with Emulator fails - requires a project but doesn't set one

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I'm trying to test the PubSub emissions locally on my NodeJS app.
I'm following these tutorials:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator - setting the Emulator
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-event - app specific

As instructed in the first link, I started the emulator by invoking:
`gcloud beta emulators pubsub start --project=test`, and set the env variables by `$(gcloud beta emulators pubsub env-init)`.

But in contrast to what appears in the tutorial, when I check which env variables needs to be set by `gcloud beta emulators pubsub env-init`, there is no project-id. And as I run the test I receive the following error: `Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment...`

So I tried to set a project manually by invoking `gcloud config set project test`.

the tutorial specifies about the project parameter ('test' in my case):

> The string does not need to represent a real Google Cloud project because the Pub/Sub emulator runs locally.

However, as I run the test, it now gives the following error: `5 NOT_FOUND: Requested project not found or user does not have access to it (project=test)...`

*In both cases, the error comes from the `publish` function

What can I do in this case? Must I use an existing project in oppose to what's claimed in the tutorial, or else what am I missing?

The test:

```
describe('SubscribeController', () => {
  const pubSub = new PubSub();
  let subscribeController: SubscribeController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: LoggerService,
          useValue: {},
        },
      ],
      controllers: [SubscribeController],
    }).compile();

    subscribeController = moduleRef.get<SubscribeController>(SubscribeController);
  });

  describe('1 emissions tests', () => {
    it('1.1 when receives an event emission, should log via the LoggerService', async () => {
      const logEventMock = jest.spyOn(subscribeController, 'logEvent').mockImplementation(async function(event:string) {});
      const topic = pubSub.topic('EVENT');
      await topic.publish(Buffer.from('hello'));
      await logEventMock.mock.results[0].value;
      expect(logEventMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello');
    });
  });
});
```

The tested subject:

```
@Controller()
export class SubscribeController {
  constructor(private readonly _loggerService: LoggerService) {
  }

  @EventPattern('EVENT')
  async logEvent(event: string): Promise<void> {
    await this._loggerService.logEvent(event);
  }

  @EventPattern('ERROR')
  async logError(error: string): Promise<void> {
    await this._loggerService.logError(error);
  }
}
```

PubSub dependency in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^2.17.0",
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need first to start the emulator with this code:

```
gcloud beta emulators pubsub start --project=test
```

Then, you need to run your code. If you didn’t start the emulator, you’ll get this error: `The string does not need to represent a real Google Cloud project because the Pub/Sub emulator runs locally.`

If you still get the error `Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment`, execute this command: `gcloud info`, which will show you the account and project you are using. And with this command: `gcloud projects list`, you’ll be able to see the available projects for your account. Then use this command: `gcloud config set project test` to set a real project. After that, you can follow the tutorial.

Your API needs to connect with the parameters of the emulator. `Port=8085 and localhost(127.0.1)`.

You can see this documentation about [testing apps locally with the emulator](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#:%7E:text=The%20string%20does%20not%20need,Pub%2FSub%20emulator%20runs%20locally.&text=This%20indicates%20that%20the%20Pub,Creating%20a%20topic%20or%20subscription).

Comment: Thanks! However, with your solution I'd by doing what I'm trying to avoid - using a real project, since the tutorial states it does not have to be a real one. Do you think it might not be possible, and only via a real project can I test the emulator locally?

Comment: Try to use a valid name for Google Cloud project ID string. Not necessarily a real project. But must follow certain rules. Meaning must look like a valid GC Project Id. You can see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#before_you_begin).Must finish with numbers. Once the emulator is running, don't stop it, leave it running.

Comment: @tomwe Did my comment help you?